# Elegant way to either getOption or set default in functions

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to set it up so that the function checks if an option is set, and if not - uses the default?

When building a function you can set defaults:

```
test1 <- function(x = NULL) { 
  return(x) 
} 

> test1()
NULL
```

You can also lookup an option

```
options("test2.x" = NULL)
test2 <-  function(x = getOption("test2.x")) {
   return(x) 
}

> test2()
NULL
```

Comment: I think it's right there in the `default` argument of `?getOption` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I think so too. Answer?

Comment: you can, I have to run.

Comment: Well, that's embarassingly straightforward. Someone come get their checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getOption` has a parameter, `default`, that does this automatically. For example:

```
test1 <- function(x = getOption("test1.x", default = NULL)) { return(x) } 
> test1()
NULL
```

Hat tips to @BenBolker